# debugging a java.lang.VerifyError

Tags: java, debugging

I am getting a java.lang.VerifyError, on the page of oracle it says it's thrown because of inconsistencies or security problems. But this can be an awful lot of things and I don't even know what I'm looking for or in which class I should look.

The error message doesn't clarify things either:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: proto/lua/libraries/ProtoLib$Lib1, method: call signature: ()Lproto/lua/LuaValue;) Wrong return type in function
```

What inconsistencies should I be on the lookout for? And can anyone tell in what class I should look based on that error?

Any general help/info on the topic of these exceptions would be appreciated too

**EDIT:** I rewrote much of the Lua Library and until I got this error that worked perfectly fine in every aspect and I use Java SE 6 Update 26

**EDIT:** Whole error:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: proto/lua/libraries/ProtoLib$Lib1, method: call signature: ()Lproto/lua/LuaValue;) Wrong return type in function
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at proto.lua.libraries.LibFunction.bind(LibFunction.java:169)
    at proto.lua.libraries.LibFunction.bind(LibFunction.java:152)
    at proto.lua.libraries.ProtoLib.call(ProtoLib.java:26)
    at proto.lua.otherstuff.OneArgFunction.call(OneArgFunction.java:66)
    at proto.lua.LuaValue.load(LuaValue.java:1358)
    at proto.lua.RavenLua.standardGlobals(RavenLua.java:100)
    at proto.ProjectPROTO.<clinit>(ProjectPROTO.java:51)
Could not find the main class: proto.ProjectPROTO.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1
```

*All proto.xxx.xxx.xxx classes are part of the source*

**EDIT:** Well apparently the error was caused since I forgot some @Override annotations, don't know what made them start giving errors though.

Comment: Which JVM and version are you using? If you downloaded the Lua JAR from somewhere, have you checked to ensure it wasn't corrupted?

Comment: Whats the code that throws this error?

Comment: What do you mean by that the classes are not compiled? Are the proto/lua/* classes part of this project, as source code instead of a library?

Comment: @Kal, it's a pretty big class and since I suspect the problem lies in the hiarchy. I could post only the constructors if that would help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is the full stack trace? It should show that which class is calling that method. Probably the reason is that the code is being executed against a different version of the library that it was compiled against, and there is some incompatible change between those library versions (from the error message it appears to be a different method return type).

If that error is not about any library, but about your own code, then do a clean build. The compiler should produce a compile error about all things which may cause a verify error at runtime. Or if the source code is correct, it should rebuild all the class files correctly.

Comment: A clean build didn't help, but somehow thinking of 'cleaning' made me check all the failing classes and I noticed there were some classes that were overriding methods without a @Override annotation, out of habit I fixed that and just for the heck of it I ran my code again and now the VerifyError is gone. No idea what happened but thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The single biggest source of java.lang.Verify errors is JVM version incompatibilities between your dependent libraries and your main application. So if you are running your application using Java 5 and the dependent library was compiled with Java 6 you could run into issues. I would start off investigating what version of Java was used to compile the version of Protolib? you are using.

Comment: Protolib isn't compiled and every compiled library I use worked until well, half an hour ago

Comment: @Dasdasd - wait, you are saying your application was not changed in any way and then stopped working about half hour before you posted the question? Something must have changed in that window, could you expand your original question to include what it might be?

Comment: Well basically I am trying to combine some of my working classes by making them extend a class ('LuaUserdata') instead of creating a new one and attaching itself to it. That worked for 3 of the 4, the last one 'Part' causes my headaches.

Comment: Did you use any byte code manipulation when converting the classes? Also, do your proto libraries rely on ***any*** external libraries that are not present as source in your project?

Answer (score 1):

As per @Perception's answer, but I would add:

The most usual reason is your runtime environment is using a different (older) JVM version to your compile environment.

Comment: The odd thing is that I'm not using compiled libraries in the code where I suspect the error is caused